# Entering figure in the header in exam class

Tags: floats, exam

I am using the exam class for preparing a question paper. Can anyone tell me how to insert a figure in the header? My aim is to insert the university's letterhead at the top of the paper. 
regards
Leo

Comment: I would use `tikz` (absolute positioning on page) plus `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help?  There are 3 places where (left, middle, right) an image can be located. The proposed solution also includes first/running header and footer.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots,geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,automata}
%\headheight 10pt
\geometry{paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textheight=25cm,textwidth=19cm,top=2cm,footskip=1cm}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\firstpageheader{\sffamily 25 March, 2014
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}                      %left  header
{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\huge{\bfseries First Midterm}}}    % middle header
{\sffamily Prof. ABC}                                            % right header
\runningheader{\sffamily Math 101}{xxxx}{\sffamily 25 March 2014}
\runningheadrule
\firstpagefooter{}{\sffamily Page~\thepage\ of~\numpages\ }{\iflastpage{\sffamily End of Exam}{\sffamily Next page, Please\ldots}}
\runningfooter{}{\sffamily Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{\iflastpage{\sffamily End of Exam}{Next page, Please\ldots}}
\begin{document}

\textbullet\ {\color{red} This exam has \numquestions\ questions, totaling \numpoints\ points and \numbonuspoints\ bonus points.}

\begin{questions}
\question[10] This is question one

\lipsum[1]

\question[10] This is question two

\lipsum[2]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```